# Unexpected "Multiple definition" errors in C++ with Qt5

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, qt5

I have working code which uses GLFW in C++. Now I want to use it with Qt.
I'm using a class which inherits QOpenGLWidget. The problem is that in my utils.h and main.cpp files are giving multiple definition errors for all the functions in them while they are defined only once.

make log:

```
Makefile:597: warning: overriding recipe for target 'main.o'
Makefile:432: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'main.o'
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o Rachaita3DFrontend main.o mainwindow.o oglwidget.o main.o moc_mainwindow.o   -lGLEW -lglfw -lGLX -lSOIL -lstdc++ -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -lpthread   
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `ToCompleteEntity(DataStructs::Type*, DataStructs::Position*, DataStructs::Rotation*, DataStructs::Scale*, DataStructs::Mesh*, DataStructs::Shader*)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `ToCompleteEntity(DataStructs::Type*, DataStructs::Position*, DataStructs::Rotation*, DataStructs::Scale*, DataStructs::Mesh*, DataStructs::Shader*)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `LoadTexture(char const*, int, int, MeshInstance)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x130): multiple definition of `LoadTexture(char const*, int, int, MeshInstance)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x130): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `key_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x270): multiple definition of `key_callback(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x270): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `Update()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x290): multiple definition of `Update()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x290): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `gl()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2a0): multiple definition of `gl()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2a0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o:(.bss+0x10): multiple definition of `window'; main.o:(.bss+0x10): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o:(.bss+0x8): multiple definition of `shader'; main.o:(.bss+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `mesh'; main.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `resize(int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x390): multiple definition of `resize(int, int)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x390): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `LoadToVAO(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, char const*, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0x3a0): multiple definition of `LoadToVAO(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >, char const*, int, int)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3a0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `vecTofloat(std::vector<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::allocator<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xba0): multiple definition of `vecTofloat(std::vector<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::allocator<glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xba0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `vecTofloat(std::vector<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::allocator<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xca0): multiple definition of `vecTofloat(std::vector<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0>, std::allocator<glm::vec<3, float, (glm::qualifier)0> > >)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xca0): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `loadOBJ(char const*, char const*, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text+0xe20): multiple definition of `loadOBJ(char const*, char const*, int, int)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xe20): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `initGL()':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1b30): multiple definition of `initGL()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1b30): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: oglwidget.o: in function `OGLWidget::initializeGL()':
oglwidget.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `GL::initGL()'
/usr/bin/ld: oglwidget.o: in function `OGLWidget::paintGL()':
oglwidget.cpp:(.text+0x71): undefined reference to `GL::gl()'
/usr/bin/ld: oglwidget.o: in function `OGLWidget::resizeGL(int, int)':
oglwidget.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `GL::resize(int, int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:167: Rachaita3DFrontend] Error 1
```

Here is a simple example for the same.

main1.cpp:

```
#include "utils1.h"
#include "main1.h"

void printSomething2{
    printSomething();
}
```

main1.h:

```
#ifndef MAIN1_H_INCLUDED
#define MAIN1_H_INCLUDED

class foo{
    public:
        static void printSomething();
};

#endif
```

utils1.h:

```
#ifndef UTILS1_H_INCLUDED
#define UTILS1_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

void printSomething(){
    std::cout<<"something.";
}

#endif
```

Example.cpp file calling printSomething()

```
#include "main1.h"

int main(){
    foo::printSomething();
    return 0;
}
```

GCC log after compiling Example.cpp:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc4ft1pF.o: in function `main':
Ogl1.cpp:(.text+0x5): undefined reference to `foo::printSomething()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To encourage other users to help you with your problem, please consider converting you program to a (minimal example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example].

Comment: I updated the question with a simple example that does the same.

Comment: This command is wrong: `g++ -Wl,-O1 -o Rachaita3DFrontend main.o mainwindow.o oglwidget.o main.o moc_mainwindow.o   -lGLEW -lglfw -lGLX -lSOIL -lstdc++ -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -lpthread`  , it should not have `main.o` twice.  You have made a mistake somewhere in the build configuration (not in the source code). The warnings suggest you have two different entries for main.o in your Makefile.

Comment: The "simple example" you add is an entirely different problem to the one that occurs in the initial question  (the problem in your later example is that you never define `foo::printSomething`)

Comment: OK I'll make an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command is wrong:

```
g++ -Wl,-O1 -o Rachaita3DFrontend main.o mainwindow.o oglwidget.o main.o moc_mainwindow.o -lGLEW -lglfw -lGLX -lSOIL -lstdc++ -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so -lpthread
```

It should not have `main.o` twice. You have made a mistake somewhere in the build configuration (not in the source code). The warnings suggest you have two different entries for main.o in your Makefile.

The problem in your "simple example" at the end is that you never define `foo::printSomething`. That is a different function to `printSomething` (unqualified).